# Setup Postgres SSL connection from wildfly

Tags: postgresql, ssl, wildfly, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to setup an SSL connection from wildfly to CloudSQL Postgres DB.
After having downloaded ssl certs from CloudSQL (server-ca.pem, client-cert.pem and client-key.pem), I created keystore and trustore in the following way:

```
keytool -import -alias server -file server-ca.pem -keystore truststore.jks -storepass password
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem -inkey client-key.pem -out client.p12 -name client
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass password -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass password -alias client
```

Then I've changed JAVA_OPTS env variable, to provide the keystore created:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password"
```

Then I've changed postgres datasource in standalone.xml:

```
jdbc:postgresql://XX.XX.XX.XX:5432/db?sslmode=require
```

At wildfly startup, I got the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud SQL creates a server certificate automatically when you create your instance. As long as the server certificate is valid, the certificate has an expiration date; after that date, it is no longer valid, and clients are not able to establish a secure connection to your instance using that certificate.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ssl-instance

Comment: Thank you for you response. Client and server certificates are valid for sure, since I've created some days ago. I think the problem is related to the wildfly configuration

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/ssl/, the default SSL Socket factory is the LibPQFactory. It is not directly stated, but if you want to use "core" Java mechanisms to access keystore/truststore for datasource SSL handling (like you did by specifying `javax.net.ssl.*` parameters), you should use `org.postgresql.ssl.DefaultJavaSSLFactory` by providing sslfactory parameter:

```
sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.DefaultJavaSSLFactory
```

So in your case, connection url will look like:

```
jdbc:postgresql://XX.XX.XX.XX:5432/db?sslmode=require&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.DefaultJavaSSLFactory
```